# In which config file i can put this "max.task.idle.ms"?

Tags: apache-kafka, config, ksqldb

There is a problem i am facing with ksql joins and supposedly it can solve by `max.task.idle.ms` , but problem is that i am unable to find where i should put this.

I tried to make changes in `/etc/kafka/server.properties` but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/kafka/server.properties` is a config file for the Kafka broker.

I think you are looking for `/etc/ksql/ksql-server.properties`

Cf: https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/installation/server-config/index.html#setting-ksql-server-parameters